# Is there a way to make immediate window show actual tabs instead of 4 spaces when using debug.print

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access

Is there a way to force VBA to print the actual `chr(9)` or `vbTab` character into the immediate window when using `debug.print` instead of 4 spaces or whatever you define?

Let's say I want to copy some records from a table in MS Access, and have them concatenated into a string separated by the `vbTab` char, I then print the string into the immediate window in MS Access and copy that string.

I paste the string into Excel and try to use the Text Import Wizard delimited by Tab character, does it work? Absolutely not!  Excel won't recognize the Tab character but rather 4 spaces.

I need to either copy it to the clipboard using `SetText` or export it to a file and then open it in Excel.

**I don't mean to be rude, but please refrain from answers like "why don't you use | as a field separator".  I can copy the text successfully, the question is if there's a way I can copy it directly from the immediate window with the actual Tab character.**

[image: VBE options]

Comment: More important question: Why do you print to the immediate window and copy strings from there?

Comment: @nacroid it's quick and lazyness.  IMHO it's faster than having to save a file and then open it in excel, or the overhead of having to create a MSFORMS object just to copy the string to the clipboard.

Comment: You can export from access to excel directly, it will save you the headache.

Comment: @warcupine without having to save an actual file to disk?

Comment: No... but how are you getting the value into excel without having an excel opened? And a single excel sheet is just a couple MB. Maybe i'm missing what the problem is here?

Comment: @Warcupine that's the point, i have to do this copy and paste of records in a table to an excel, in various ranges or sheets or however I see fit.  Please don't get offended, but you're missing the point on the question, i don't mean/want to discuss alternatives, just if it's possible to show actual Tab characters in the immediate window.  Thanks

Comment: I assure you I'm not offended, you're just going about this in the worst possible way. Everything you asked for is easily doable in a much easier manner. Best of luck to you.

Comment: I haven't voted on anything about this question... but now that you mention it.

Comment: Not sure what went on here (in comments and voting), but it's a legitimate question imo.

Comment: may I just put [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.copyfromrecordset) here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I don't mean/want to discuss alternatives, just if it's possible to
>   show actual Tab characters in the immediate window.

The answer is no.

Answer (score 1):

@Nacorid and @Warcupine: Jose R's actual question is legit. In my case (in Word for example), I've needed to dump the current values of some Application object properties so that I can then copy/paste them into Excel, to form a multi-column table.  What would be most desirable is to just do something like this:

```
With Application
    Debug.Print "UserName" & vbTab & .UserName
    Debug.Print "UserInitials" & vbTab & .UserInitials
    Debug.Print "DefaultSaveFormat" & vbTab & .DefaultSaveFormat
    Debug.Print "RecentFiles.Maximum" & vbTab & .RecentFiles.Maximum
End With
```

and then copy/paste those results directly into an Excel spreadsheet.

But, no, I have to use a two step process:

```
With Application
    Debug.Print "UserName" & "~" & .UserName
    Debug.Print "UserInitials" & "~" & .UserInitials
    Debug.Print "DefaultSaveFormat" & "~" & .DefaultSaveFormat
    Debug.Print "RecentFiles.Maximum" & "~" & .RecentFiles.Maximum
End With
```

then copy/paste the results of that into Word, do a replace of "~" with "^t" and then copy/paste those results into the Excel spreadsheet.  That technique works, of course, but it is counter-intuitive (and annoying) that the VBE designers actively prevent a programmer from doing what they need to do: print an actual Tab character to the Immediate window. A better design would have been to have Tab(n) operate as it does, when needed, but also allow vbTab or Chr(9) to print the Tab character.

And a suggestion about comment style: it's great to offer alternative ways to do what you think the person asking the question is trying to do, but it's very off-putting to make judgements about their attempted solution or why they've asked the question that they've asked.  I comes across as arrogant and ill-informed given that you can't possibly have much insight into whatever larger context and circumstances drove the person to ask their particular question.

Answer (score 0):

The Immediate Window's representation of `chr(9)` or `vbTab` is 4 spaces.  You can verify this by printing `chr(9)` or `vbTab`, clicking into the Immediate Window and pressing Backspace and then typing a few spaces and pressing Backspace.

There is no way to change this, as far as I'm aware.